# Rails 3.2+: can I configure size of rails SQL cache?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, activerecord, memcached

We're using memcached as our main cache store and it works great.  But we have to decide to use it and decide on expiration.  When queries are expensive or frequent, they are good candidates for caching.

But caching requires the little overhead of:

```
Rails.cache.fetch 'some-key', expires_in: some-time do
  some-query-result
end
```

This style of caching has some downsides -- it's not something you can just do willy-nilly (as some of our team recently learned the hard way).  If you cache "everything" or don't put rational expiration (or worse, don't pick unique cache keys) things can quickly become a mess.  And they did; so we have backed off.  Until we refactor more completely, we would like to benefit from ActiveRecord SQL caching as much as we can.

ActiveRecord SQL caching is "free", if not optimal.  I cannot find where (or even if) how much memory is use is configured.

How can I specify the amount of memory used by ActiveRecord SQL caching?

(Rails 3.2, moving to 4.0 soonish, Ruby 1.9.3)

Comment: I was under the impression that Rails' SQL caching uses the same cache as everything else (and thus is based on whatever you set `config.cache_store` to). That's certainly the sense I get from the relevant guide.